# How to display some multiline text?

Tags: iphone

For the about section of my app, I want to display some multiline text. But which one is actually better for this? UITextView or UIWebView? What are the benefits of these, which should I prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format the text with different fonts, colors, etc, UIWebView is for you. Otherwise, UITextView should be just fine.